# Skip loading a certain div when it's on mobile/tablet device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `display:none;` in order to hide a certain `div` and display another `div` when it's **displayed on mobile/tablet browsers** but the loading time is kind of slow.

Is there anyway the browser can **skip loading the `div`** that I want to hide when it's on smaller screen?

Currently, when it runs on smaller screen, the browser still load the info of that div now I want to skip it completely.

Comment: I'm not sure browser can do that. You have to do it in server side.

Comment: You mean skip loading the images that are part of that div?

Comment: How much content do you have inside the div? If that's a lot, you might be better off serving a different page altogether.

Comment: I don't want to have a different page so that's why I put everything in 1 page and use css to hide it when the browser scales down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to skip loading content (client-side anyway), but you can delay loading content until you have figured out whether it is needed or not. For image tags you can simply set the src attribute (using jquery or whatever) after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

put the div html fragments that will not be loaded for mobile...
load and append the div fragment only when the screen is not small.

main html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

div fragment to be loaded only for big screens:

```
<div>some content not visible on small screens</div>
```

main html - jquery js code to be executed when the screen is not small:

```
$(function(){
   if(/*screen check condition*/){
      $('#container').load('div-frag.html');
   }
});
```